# call to a member function with() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-4, repository

I'm referencing the http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories/ and I got the call to a member function with() on a non-object. The error comes from 
AbstractRepository Class.

```
public function make(array $with = array())
{
    return $this->model->with($with);
}
```

here My SpeakerRepository interface.

```
<?php namespace Amh\Storage;

interface  SpeakerRepository
{ 
    public function all();

    public function find($id);

    public function create($input);

    public function update($input);

    public function delete($id);
}

<?php namespace Amh\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Speaker as Speaker;
use File;
use Input;
use Amh\FileService\Photo\File as ImageFile;
class EloquentSpeakerRepository extends AbstractEloquentRepository implements SpeakerRepository
{
protected $speaker;

protected $file;

public function __construct(ImageFile $file,Speaker $speaker)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->speaker = $speaker;
}


 public function create($input)
 {
    $imageName = $this->file->createImageName($input['image']);

    try 
    {
        $this->file->store($input['image'],$imageName);

        $input = array('name'=>$input['name'],
                'image'=> 'photos/'.$imageName,
                'desc'=>$input['desc']
        );

        return Speaker::create($input);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->file->delete($imageName);

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }

 public function update($input)
 {      
    $speaker = $this->find($input['id']);

    $oldFile = $speaker->image;

    $imageName = $this->file->createImageName($input['image']);

    try 
    {

        $this->file->store($input['image'],$imageName);

        $speaker->name = $input['name'];
        $speaker->image = 'photos/'.$imageName;
        $speaker->desc = $input['desc'];
        $speaker->save();

        $this->file->delete($oldFile);
        return true;

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->file->delete($imageName);

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

 }
 /**
  * Delete speaker information from database and speaker's image from the specified location
  */
 public function  delete($id)
 {
     $speaker = $this->find($id);

     $filePath = $speaker->image;

     $this->file->delete($filePath);

     return  $speaker->delete();
 }
}

<?php namespace Amh\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
abstract class AbstractEloquentRepository 
{

protected $model;

public function __construct()
{

}

  public function all(array $with = array())
  {
    $entity = $this->make($with);

    return $entity->get();
  }


public function find($id, array $with = array())
{
    $entity = $this->make($with);

    return $entity->find($id);
}


public function getFirstBy($key, $value, array $with = array())
{
    return $this->make($with)->where($key, '=', $value)->first();
}


public function getManyBy($key, $value, array $with = array())
{
    return $this->make($with)->where($key, '=',$value)->get();
}



public function make(array $with = array())
{
    return $this->model->with($with);
}


public function has($relation, array $with = array())
{
  $entity = $this->make($with);

  return $entity->has($relation)->get();
}
}

<?php namespace Amh\Storage;
use App\Models\Speaker;
use Reference;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Amh\FileService\Photo\File as ImageFile;
class StorageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
{


    $this->app->bind('Amh\Storage\SpeakerRepository','Amh\Storage\EloquentSpeakerRepository');
    $this->registerSpeakerRepository();
     }


public function registerSpeakerRepository()
{
     $this->app->bind('SpeakerRepository',function()
                {
                    return new EloquentSpeakerRepository($this->app->make('Amh\FileService\Photo\File'),new EloquentSpeakerRepository);
                }                            
        );
}
}
```

Would anyone what the problem here is? Thanks..

Comment: You're going to want to post more code. It's possible that you made an error on one of the steps, such as `$this->model = $model;` within `EloquentUserRepository`, or something. It's not possible to tell unless you post more code.

Comment: If you're still stumped, you can always get a copy of the code [right here](https://github.com/cribbb/cribbb/blob/master/app/Cribbb/Repositories/AbstractRepository.php).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I add more code.